# Access php array in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have a object with a method like this: `$foo->getId()` which returns an `integer`, and i have an array like:

```
$array(
     1=> array(
            "parent_id" => 14
     ),
     2=> array(
            "parent_id" => 15
     )
);
```

I need to access `parent_id` inside the subarray in smarty using the `$foo->getId()` as index key for `$array`, something like:

```
{$array[$foo->getId()].parent_id}
```

also tried just:

```
{$array[$foo->getId()]}
```

But both return error:

```
syntax error: unidentified token
```

What am i not doing right?

Comment: might have to use `{php}{/php}` for that `$foo->getId()` which ver smarty?

Comment: i'm using `{$foo->getId()}` in other parts without the `{php}` so that i know works, i'm not sure about the version, should be a recent one, let me check that.

Comment: @amosrivera But doesn't necessarily mean that you could use it as an array index.

Comment: certainly, me not knowing is exactly why i'm asking.

Comment: Or just switch to Twig. Despite of being faster and having more useful features like template inheritance, it will also allow what you are trying to do here: `{{ array[foo.id].parent_id }}` (or if you want an explicit method call: `{{ array[foo.getId()].parent_id }}`)

Comment: I've posted a working example, which should be close to your situation below. Please have a look at the version numbers first. Maybe upgrading helps. If not, I think there's some strange error in your more complex code. Try to create a simple test like I did to verify if the error remains the same.

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting the answer, i jut haven't had the time to try it out. I will let you know if it works for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try:

```
{$array.$foo->getId().parent_id}
```

If this does not work, I think you have to assign the ID to an other variable beforehand:

```
{assign var=foo_id value=`$foo->getId()`}{$array.$foo_id.parent_id}
```

In Smarty 3, this should work:

```
{$array.{$foo->getId()}.parent_id}
```

Comment: Works also in ``if`` conditions, if someone would come across here and need it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I have just tried to get the same error as you. Funny thing is, the code runs fine. Here we go for the specs: Smarty 3.0.7 with PHP 5.3.4.

My template code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Smarty</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, {$array[2]["parent_id"]}<br/>
    Hello, {$array[$foo->getId()]["parent_id"]}<br/>    
  </body>
</html>
```

The php file:

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public function getId() {
        return 2;   
    }   
}

// ... smarty config left out ... $smarty has been assigned successfully

$foo = new Foo();

$array = array(
   1 => array("parent_id" => 14),
   2 => array("parent_id" => 15)
);

$smarty->assign('array', $array);
$smarty->assign('foo', $foo);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

?>
```

The Output:

```
Hello, 15
Hello, 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array[$foo->getId()]["parent_id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use a variable that way:

```
$a=array(
     1 => array(
            "parent_id" => 14
     ),
     2 => array(
            "parent_id" => 15
     )
);
```

Then you can access your array like this:

```
$a[1]["parent_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't forget to pass the tow variables to Smarty

```
$smarty->assign('array', $array);
$smarty->assign('foo', $foo);
```

And, in your Smarty Template, use :

```
{$array[$foo->getId()]["parent_id"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used smarty, but in PHP you can do:

```
<?php

class foo {
   public function getId() {
        return (int)2;
    }
}

$array = array(
     1 => array(
            "parent_id" => 14
     ),
     2 => array(
            "parent_id" => 15
     )
 );

$foo = new Foo;

echo $array[(int)$foo->getId()]['parent_id'];
//15
```

I've type casted as integer `(int)$foo->getID()` because the `$array` indexes are integers, enclosing them in brackets `{}` type castes them in strings.

(Maybe you should look at `Foo::getID()` and see if returns a string)

In smarty then, you could do something like this (theoretically, since I can't test it in smarty):

```
{$array[(int)$foo->getId()]['parent_id']}

//Also check if this works, but I suspect it shouldn't (the syntax it's not valid PHP)
{$array.(int)$foo->getId().parent_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. From the php file assign object to smarty variable 'foo'

```
{assign var="val" value=$foo->getId()}
{$arr.$val.parent_id}
```